# Java Translator API

Tags: java, translation, google-translate, microsoft-translator

Are there any free online/offline translator APIs for Java out there that do not require you to pay or register like Google and Microsoft do? I've been trying to find some but all of them have a limit or require payment of some form. All I need is to translate an occasional string or two. If not, is there a workaround to Google translate? I've seen a post involving the use of a spreadsheet but it was in JavaScript and I need this for Java not JavaScript.

I'm okay with registering. It's the pay that gets to me because I'm releasing this program to public.

Comment: Presumably you could write a screen-scraper for Google or one of the other services.

Comment: *"I've seen a post"*  Where?  What URL?

Comment: BTW - the main  link from the MS info. page (see extra tags above) states.. *"The set of offers includes an option for FREE use of the API."* Why is that offer not suitable for your app.?

Answer (score 0):

microsoft Translator offers free 2 million characters per month.

Comment: MS requires your credit card data for subscription, even in free plan. It's no-go for most soberly thinking humans, but objectively it's also a blocker for those, who do not use credit cards.